# Sum using Merged Cells

Tags: excel, formula

I've been trying to search formula to help me with this case, and based on search sumif based on merged cells is a BIG NO-NO. However, i cannot overwrite the format of the table. Therefore Im asking help for a formula to execute my needed output.

On the image attached,

I need to sum all figures on Column T based on the Remark in Column W.
Column Y will serve as the label of the output on Column Z.
Manually Calculated it should have sum as follows:
Under Rebates: 1467.77
45 Days: 1723.12
60 Days: 9.85

Appreciate if you can please help me with this problem.
Thank you in advance!

SUM BASED ON MERGED CELL

[image]

Comment: Use a helper column (in X perhaps) to repeat the merged cell value from Y, but for each row.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your tip.
Is there an easy formula to automate it in Col. X ?

Column A to W is manually filled up by each individual. As much as possible I dont want to stress out each individual in adding another row to fill out.
And as you may notice, Remarks vary on each transactions.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: In `X3`, perhaps use the formula `=IF(W3="",X2,W3)`, and drag down. You may need to change the commas to semicolons depending on your version of Excel.

Comment: worked perfectly! thank you now I can use sumif function with ease.
have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

In X3, perhaps use the formula **=IF(W3="",X2,W3**), and drag down. You may need to change the commas to semicolons depending on your version of Excel. – BigBen

Comment: I actually really like this idea. It helped me out. Thanks for sharing